# "/bin/rm: cannot remove files .. No such file or directory " though they exist

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am trying to fix ffmpeg library conflicts  between manually installed and John Sverissons's ppa. In this context I attemped to remove `libavcodec.so libavutil.so, libswscale.so, libswresample.so, libavresample.so, libavfilter.so` in my system by doing

```
locate -0b libavfilter.so | xargs -0 rm
```

for each *.so files above.

I could remove all above files except `libavfilter.so`
When I issue `locate -b libavfilter.so` it lists paths but when I attempt to remove it I get

```
 /bin/rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavfilter.so': No such file or directory
```

What happens here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that the file exists, other than by using `locate`? Locate uses a database, so you may be looking at stale information.

Three solutions:

- Use the `--existing` option for `locate`
- Run `sudo updatedb` before running `locate`
- Try again tomorrow, after the daily cron jobs have run

Comment: You are right. `locate --existing -b libavfilter.so` returns empty line. Thank you.